# What's the practical difference between a bit and a bit vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have been struggling with one assignment in VHDL that I need to get done soon. Any help and/or advise would be really appreciated.

My question is the following: are all signals (in a diagram linked below) considered to be bit vectors?

diagram => http://s014.radikal.ru/i328/1505/06/472c30243696.png

[image]

Here is the code that just does not want to compile:

```
entity sum1_1 is
port(a3,a4: in bit;
q1,q2: out bit);
end sum1_1;
architecture struct of sum1_1 is
begin
q1 <= a3 xor a4;
q2 <= a3 and a4;
end struct;


entity mul2_2 is
port (a1,a2,b1,b2: in bit;
p1,p2,p3,p4: out bit);
end mul2_2;
architecture f_mul2_2 of mul2_2 is
component sum1_1
port(a3,a4: in bit;
q1,q2: out bit);
end component;
signal k2,k3,k4,k5: bit;
begin
p1 <= a1 and b1;
k2 <= a1 and b2;
k3 <= a2 and b1;
k4 <= a2 and b2;
l1: sum1_1 port map (k2,k3,p2,k5);
l2: sum1_1 port map (k4,k5,p3,p4);
end f_mul2_2;


Entity lab32 is
Generic (N:natural:=4);
Port (x,w,y:in bit_vector (1 to N);
l,r,z:out bit_vector (1 to N));
End lab32;
Architecture func of lab32 is
Component mul2_2
port (a1,a2,b1,b2: in bit;
p1,p2,p3,p4: out bit);
end component;
signal g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6: bit_vector (1 to N);
begin
lab322: for i in 1 to N generate
first_bit: if (i=1) generate
first: mul2_2 port map (a1=>w(1), a2=>x(1), b1=>y(2), b2=>y(1), p1=>g1(1), p2=>g2(1), p3=>g3(1), p4=>g4(1));
second: mul2_2 port map (a1=>g1(1), a2=>g2(1), b1=>y(4), b2=>y(3), p1=>r(1), p2=>l(1), p3=>g5(1), p4=>g6(1));
end generate first_bit;
middle_bit: if (i>1) and (i<N) generate 
first_m: mul2_2 port map (a1=>w(i), a2=>x(i), b1=>g3(i-1), b2=>g4(i-1), p1=>g1(i), p2=>g2(i), p3=>g3(i), p4=>g4(i));
second_m: mul2_2 port map (a1=>g1(i), a2=>g2(i), b1=>g5(i-1), b2=>g6(i-1), p1=>r(i), p2=>l(i), p3=>g5(i), p4=>g6(i));
end generate middle_bit;
end_bit: if (i=N) generate
first_e: mul2_2 port map (a1=>w(i), a2=>x(i), b1=>g3(i-1), b2=>g4(i-1), p1=>g1(i), p2=>g2(i), p3=>z(2), p4=>z(1));
second_e: mul2_2 port map (a1=>g1(i), a2=>g2(i), b1=>g5(i-1), b2=>g6(i-1), p1=>r(i), p2=>l(i), p3=>z(4), p4=>z(3));
end generate end_bit;
end generate lab322;
end func;


entity lab32test is 
Generic(N:natural:=4); 
end lab32test; 
architecture behavior of lab32test is 
component lab32 
Port(x,w,y:in bit_vector (1 to N);
l,r,z:out bit_vector (1 to N));
end component; 
signal x,w,y:in bit_vector (1 to N); 
signal l,r,z:out bit_vector (1 to N);
begin 
p1: lab32 port map (x,w,y,l,r,z:bit_vector (1 to N)); 

x<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'0' after 100 ns,
'0' after 150 ns,
'0' after 200 ns,
'0' after 250 ns,
'0' after 300 ns,
'0' after 350 ns,
'1' after 400 ns,
'1' after 450 ns,
'1' after 500 ns,
'1' after 550 ns,
'1' after 600 ns,
'1' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
w<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'0' after 100 ns,
'0' after 150 ns,
'1' after 200 ns,
'1' after 250 ns,
'1' after 300 ns,
'1' after 350 ns,
'0' after 400 ns,
'0' after 450 ns,
'0' after 500 ns,
'0' after 550 ns,
'1' after 600 ns,
'1' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
y<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'1' after 100 ns,
'1' after 150 ns,
'0' after 200 ns,
'0' after 250 ns,
'1' after 300 ns,
'1' after 350 ns,
'0' after 400 ns,
'0' after 450 ns,
'1' after 500 ns,
'1' after 550 ns,
'0' after 600 ns,
'0' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
end behavior;
```

My initial guess is that I've made a mistake somewhere in the "generic" operator or in the testing function.

Answer (score 1):

We have a language problem here. From the perspective of the VHDL standard there is no relationship between the diagram you provide and your question.  A bit_vector is an array of elements of the type bit.  An array of bit can have a length from null to the greatest value possible in type natural plus one (0 is the lowest value).

```
type BIT_VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>)of BIT;
```

VHDL is strongly typed and assignment to a bit_vector must be an array  of type bit, a closely related type  or a string literal that has an implicit type conversion to a bit_vector.  Array types are closely related when both have the same element type.

Assignment also requires the length of the target and expression on the right hand side have the same length.

There were a couple of errors in the way of understanding your question from your example code.

The signal declarations found as architecture declarative items should not have mode:

```
architecture behavior of lab32test is 
component lab32 
Port(x,w,y:in bit_vector (1 to N);
l,r,z:out bit_vector (1 to N));
end component; 
signal x,w,y:in bit_vector (1 to N); 
signal l,r,z:out bit_vector (1 to N);
begin
```

These signal declarations should be

```
signal x,w,y: bit_vector (1 to N);  -- in 
signal l,r,z: bit_vector (1 to N);  -- out
```

The port map for p1 is similarly afflicted.

```
p1: lab32 port map (x,w,y,l,r,z:bit_vector (1 to N));
```

It should either have named or positional elements without a subtype indication:

```
p1: lab32 port map (x,w,y,l,r,z); -- :bit_vector (1 to N))
```

This shows positional association.

And now we get messages saying your assigning '0' and '1' literals to bit_vectors.

The concurrent signal assignments to x and y with complex waveforms are defective.  As we see above x, w and y are bit_vectors yet you assign character literals that get implicitly converted to type bit:

```
x<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'0' after 100 ns,
'0' after 150 ns,
'0' after 200 ns,
'0' after 250 ns,
'0' after 300 ns,
'0' after 350 ns,
'1' after 400 ns,
'1' after 450 ns,
'1' after 500 ns,
'1' after 550 ns,
'1' after 600 ns,
'1' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
w<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'0' after 100 ns,
'0' after 150 ns,
'1' after 200 ns,
'1' after 250 ns,
'1' after 300 ns,
'1' after 350 ns,
'0' after 400 ns,
'0' after 450 ns,
'0' after 500 ns,
'0' after 550 ns,
'1' after 600 ns,
'1' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
y<='0', 
'0' after 50 ns, 
'1' after 100 ns,
'1' after 150 ns,
'0' after 200 ns,
'0' after 250 ns,
'1' after 300 ns,
'1' after 350 ns,
'0' after 400 ns,
'0' after 450 ns,
'1' after 500 ns,
'1' after 550 ns,
'0' after 600 ns,
'0' after 650 ns,
'1' after 700 ns,
'1' after 750 ns;
end behavior;
```

This should give you some sort of analysis time error saying you have a type mismatch during and assignment. Those character 
literal '0' and '1' values can't be converted to bit_vectors. You need expressions that provide values that are convertible (strings) that have a length matching x, w and y (length N).

You also don't have to have all the scheduled value updates in the waveforms for x, w and y with successively identical values, only change values.

Without regard to the value of N you can set all the bits of the bit_vectors x, w and y to one value using an aggregate like this:

```
x<=(others => '0'), 
(others => '0') after 50 ns, 
(others => '0') after 100 ns,
(others => '0') after 150 ns,
(others => '0') after 200 ns,
(others => '0') after 250 ns,
(others => '0') after 300 ns,
(others => '0') after 350 ns,
(others => '1') after 400 ns,
(others => '1') after 450 ns,
(others => '1') after 500 ns,
(others => '1') after 550 ns,
(others => '1') after 600 ns,
(others => '1') after 650 ns,
(others => '1') after 700 ns,
(others => '1') after 750 ns;
w<=(others => '0'), 
(others => '0') after 50 ns, 
(others => '0') after 100 ns,
(others => '0') after 150 ns,
(others => '1') after 200 ns,
(others => '1') after 250 ns,
(others => '1') after 300 ns,
(others => '1') after 350 ns,
(others => '0') after 400 ns,
(others => '0') after 450 ns,
(others => '0') after 500 ns,
(others => '0') after 550 ns,
(others => '1') after 600 ns,
(others => '1') after 650 ns,
(others => '1') after 700 ns,
(others => '1') after 750 ns;
y<=(others => '0'), 
(others => '0') after 50 ns, 
(others => '1') after 100 ns,
(others => '1') after 150 ns,
(others => '0') after 200 ns,
(others => '0') after 250 ns,
(others => '1') after 300 ns,
(others => '1') after 350 ns,
(others => '0') after 400 ns,
(others => '0') after 450 ns,
(others => '1') after 500 ns,
(others => '1') after 550 ns,
(others => '0') after 600 ns,
(others => '0') after 650 ns,
(others => '1') after 700 ns,
(others => '1') after 750 ns;
```

After which the your code analyzes.  Not this isn't an cure all for supplying stimulus to your design. For an N length of 4 this is only providing two of sixteen possible binary values of the bit_vectors.

For N = 4 you can also you string literal values comprised of characters found in the character literals of type bit (0 and 1).

For example "0101" or "1110".

And of course you can use an expression of type bit_vector with N length under certain constraints.  For instance a constant:

```
constant FIVE: bit_vector(1 to 4) := "0101";
```

You can also manage complex aggregate expressions based on N and and ascending or descending range.

Should you find your design doesn't operate as expected after it analyzes (compiles), elaborates and simulates I'd suggest you might ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! 

I just have one thing that I cannot seem to understand. 

Looking at the diagram, how can one distinguish bit from vector bit? For in other examples (which I unfortunately don't have on this computer that I am using now) all the arrows were described as bits, however as far as I'm concerned, not every arrow can be of bit type. And does this all depend on the direction of parameterization? 

P.S. Sorry for my noobness.

Comment: There isn't sufficient information in just the diagram. If your mul2_2 is provided this [diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7b/Binary_multi1.jpg) matches other than signal  name/ordinals. See the bottom of the wikipedia page on [Binary multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier). There's been a lot of 'connect up the bits in generate statements' multiplier questions lately. No one shows the handout describing what you are trying to do, how big (in bits) your multiplier is supposed to be.

Comment: VHDL is quite flexible you could have easily expressed the inputs and outputs as bit_vectors, requiring the use of selected names to specify bits used with logic operators (or to sum1_1 instantiations.